# Communication Link Failure, the last packet sent successfully, the driver has not received any packet from the server

Tags: java, mysql, server, xampp

I am deploy `java swing desktop application` for desktop pc.
It  works when I use xampp in my computer but when I share xampp server to another computer and install the setup of my `java swing application` into another pc (connected with a LAN network )
it's said:

> "Communication Link Failure, the last packet sent successfully, the
> driver has not received any packet from the server"!

Please Help